# Recursive generic function used as a predicate, compilation failure

Tags: c++, templates, stl, generic-programming

I am writing a function to compare the contents of two lists. The order of the elements don't matter, so I sort them before I compare. The lists can be of normal types `list<int>`, but also be lists of lists `list<list<int> >`.

Here is a complete stripped down example:

```
#include <list>

template <typename T>
bool lessThanInAnyOrder(T lhs, T rhs)
{
  return lhs < rhs;
}

template <typename T>
bool lessThanInAnyOrder(std::list<T> lhs, std::list<T> rhs)
{
  lhs.sort(lessThanInAnyOrder<T>);
  rhs.sort(lessThanInAnyOrder<T>);

  //Do comparisons here, but for now just:
  return false;
}

int main()
{
  std::list<int> list1;
  std::list<int> list2;
  lessThanInAnyOrder(list1, list2);
}
```

This compiles in GCC 4.3.3, but in Visual Studio 2008, it gives the following compilation error where I'm calling `lhs.sort()`:

```
error C2660: 'std::list<_Ty>::sort' : function does not take 1 arguments
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perfectly compiles for me using g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2

Comment: @Draco Ater, doesn't compile on http://www.ideone.com/Hx5St

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008. Updated the question with that information now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the function in `std::ptr_fun` with explicit type arguments:

```
lhs.sort(std::ptr_fun<T, T>(lessThanInAnyOrder<T>));
```

Answer (score 3):

Compilation fails because compiler can't select overloaded 'lessThanInAnyOrder' function to pass to list::sort. You'll have to specify it's type explicitly like [here](http://www.ideone.com/qdJ0Y).

```
template <typename T>
bool lessThanInAnyOrder(std::list<T> lhs, std::list<T> rhs)
{
  bool (*comparer)(T, T) = &lessThanInAnyOrder<T>;
  lhs.sort(comparer);
  rhs.sort(comparer);
 
  //Do comparisons here, but for now just:
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**First off**: I suppose if you want to compare collections regardless of their ordering, you might be looking for `std::set` with the [`set_difference`, `set_intersection`, `set_union` and `set_symmetric_difference` *algorithms*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/)

**To your question**

You're trying to implement sort-by-policy; if you cannot simply specialize `std::less<>` (*which exists for that exact purpose*), you could knock off a custom policy yourself: ([code running on **codepad.org**](http://codepad.org/4CoR3DQV))

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

namespace applogic
{
    template <typename T>
    struct sort_policy
    {
        typedef std::less<T> predicate_t;
    };

    template <> struct sort_policy<std::string>
    {
        struct _Cmp { bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) { return a.length()>b.length(); } };
        typedef _Cmp predicate_t;
    };

    template <typename C>
        void sort(C& cont)
    {
        typedef typename sort_policy<typename C::value_type>::predicate_t P;
        std::sort(cont.begin(), cont.end(), P());
    }

    template <typename T>
        void sort(std::list<T>& cont)
    {
        typedef typename sort_policy<T>::predicate_t P;
        cont.sort(P());
    }
}

template <class C>
    static void dump(const C& cont, const std::string& msg="")
{
    std::cout << msg;
    std::copy(cont.begin(), cont.end(), std::ostream_iterator<typename C::value_type>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    using applogic::sort;

    std::vector<int> ints;
    ints.push_back(13);
    ints.push_back(-3);
    ints.push_back(7);

    dump(ints, "before: ");
    sort(ints);
    dump(ints, "after: ");

    std::list<std::string> strings;
    strings.push_back("very very long");
    strings.push_back("tiny");
    strings.push_back("medium size");

    dump(strings, "before: ");
    sort(strings);
    dump(strings, "after: ");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess, for `int` type you can simply write like this:

```
lhs.sort();
rhs.sort();
```

[Demo.](http://www.ideone.com/7v1Yh)

Comment: Thanks, but lhs and rhs could be of type `list<list<int> >`. In that case, I need to use `lessThanInAnyOrder<list<int> >` as the predicate.

Comment: @knatten, I **suspect** `list<int>.sort(compare)` may not be defined (as it's not needed). So You can overload `lessThanInAnyOrder<int>`. Thus for `int` it will call `sort()` and for others it will call `sort(compare)`.

Comment: `list<int>.sort(compare)` does indeed work. Proof-of-concept: `bool intCompare(int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs < rhs; } list1.sort(intCompare);`

Comment: It is needed even for `list<int>` if you want to sort the ints in some other order, like largest value first.